# Android OpenGL texture / object detection

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rubiks-cube

I'm trying to perform OpenGL picking (i.e. answer the "on which object 
did the user click?" question). 
I googled it and found a few different techniques, but none is ok for 
me

- checking the pixel color with glReadPixels: I'm using textures so 
  it's not suitable
- checking the pixel alpha with glReadPixels: I'm using alpha for 
  blending so it's not suitable
- building a ray and checking collisions: ouch!, i'd prefer to not go 
  into that...
- glRenderMode(GL_SELECT): Not supported in OpenGL ES

I have been thinking about checking the stencil buffer value. I don't 
use it for its usual purpose, so each of my objects could write its ID 
in it (I have less than 255 objects). 
The problem is that I don't manage to read the stencil buffer value 
using glReadPixels. 
No problem for RGBA, but I don't manage to make it working for the 
Stencil value. 
Here is my code:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4); 
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); 
bb.position(0); 
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb); 
Log.d(TAG, "color is R"+ bb.get() + " G" + bb.get() + " B" + 
    bb.get() + " A" + bb.get()); 
// ---> This is working fine, I can read RGBA correctly 
bb.position(0); 
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_STENCIL_INDEX, 
GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb); 
    Log.d(TAG, "stencil is "+ bb.get()); 
    // ---> This is not working, looks like it isn't doing anything
```

since I still get the R value in the buffer...

I'm sure the stencil buffer is up and running because I managed to use 
it for some clipping. 
It is configured to 8bits using setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8).

Is it a limitation of the platform or is it me not doing it the right 
way? (I didn't find any actual example of reading the stencil buffer)

Also, can anybody suggest if there is any method other than using stencil buffer, to detect the object id on which the user clicks?

Comment: You mentioned using a ray to detect the collision - I think this would be the best way of detecting object interaction. If you want some code sample (high-level, non-OpenGL) take a look at the source for the Three.js library. They have a utility that utilizes rays for collision. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Comment: You were already told to use ray picking. For good reason: OpenGL's only purpose is getting nice pictures to the screen. No object and scene management, no geometry manipulation, no higher level functions. This is all it's meant for and how it should be used.

Comment: You tagged your question rubiks-cube. This means that you just have to implement ray-cube intersection. This is one of the simplest, and they are plenty of them on google.

Answer (score 3):

Actually casting a ray into the scene and checking for collisions is the method of choice for picking.

If you want to use the glReadPixels approach, you can just render your objects into the back buffer (with the object's ID encoded as a constant color) without swapping buffers. You can still render your objects fully textured for display. You only render them with their object color when the user has clicked (and the scene actually changed) and only into the back buffer without displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

> checking the pixel color with glReadPixels: I'm using textures so it's not suitable

Why this doesn't work?
You could use [glReadPixels](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) to read the [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) pixels color whether the media source is from camera or video file.

Check out the [MediaDump](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/tests/MediaDump/src/com/android/mediadump/VideoDumpView.java) project, which trying to dump every video frame into single image files using GLSurfaceView, you could modify it to do further processing or change the source to camera, both are workable. But notice the RGBA sizes setting in the [setEGLConfigChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), it will affect the [pixels reading speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126921/glreadpixles-speed-with-rgba-size-in-seteglconfigchooser).