# glReadPixles speed with RGBA size in setEGLConfigChooser

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm running [MediaDump](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/tests/MediaDump/src/com/android/mediadump/VideoDumpView.java) project, which trying to dump every video frame into single image files using GLSurfaceView. But I found that the RGBA sizes setting in the [setEGLConfigChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) playing an important role with the speed of glReadPixels.

I always set RGBA & UNSIGNED_BYTE pair in the glReadPixels, and some devices read faster with `setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, x, x)`,
and other RGBA sizes setting will make pixels reading extremely slower; While some devices read faster with `setEGLConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, x, x)`,
and other RGBA sizes setting will make pixels reading extremely slower. Maybe there are more cases.

So how does this happen? Is there a way to know the right RGBA sizes setting which will make the fastest pixels reading speed using glReadPixels ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure using [eglGetConfigAttrib](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/eglGetConfigAttrib.html) could get the fastest default values.

If `EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE == EGL_RGB_BUFFER`, then check the `EGL_RED_SIZE`, `EGL_GREEN_SIZE`, `EGL_BLUE_SIZE`, and `EGL_ALPHA_SIZE`, total equals to `EGL_BUFFER_SIZE`.

If I get (5, 6, 5, 0, 16) respectively, using `setEGLConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, x, x)` and `GL_RGB/GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5` pair in [glReadPixels](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml); If getting (8, 8, 8, 8, 32), using 
`setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, x, x)`, but the color format may be either RGBA or BGRA, after checking `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT` with [glGetIntegerv](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml), using that format and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as a pair in [glReadPixels](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).

I use the method described above and could get the fastest pixels reading environment. Not sure it's a correct way.

p.s. The basic usage of [eglGetConfigAttrib](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/eglGetConfigAttrib.html) could check the [getDetectedVersion()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/cts/CameraGLTest.java) to see how to check whether the device supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is not a safe way for determining this. This will depend a lot on the graphic hardware of the device which may vary a lot for android. You can though, try to use always the native pixel format, which should in theory be the faster for the device.

You can check the native format (before you set it) using

Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int displayPixelFormat = display.getPixelFormat();

with displayPixelFormat being PixelFormat.RGB_888, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 or 5 (BGRA_8888) for 8 8 8 8 or any other for 5 6 5.
Notice that using anything other than 565 can be tricky. You can easily get no config found errors or other config errors depending on the device and your config chooser code.

Comment: Thanks! But I saw that the [getPixelFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getPixelFormat()) was deprecated in API level 17. After July 2012, the [getPixelFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getPixelFormat()) always return PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 in the AOSP, while using [my temporary method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17129039/269342), the config value returned from [eglGetConfigAttrib](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/eglGetConfigAttrib.html) is differ from devices to devices.

Comment: If it is deprecated it is expected that from 4.2 onward all devices will have pixel format of 8888.
The eglGetConfigAttrib is different from device to device because it depends on which config of the egl configs you chose. Any device has a set of available configurations, for example one of them can have antialiasing... others can have a higher depth value. still the solution to your problem should still be chosing a configuration that matches the native format of the pixel of the device.